# React 401 error when trying to create user using fetch API in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to create a user from a react form using fetch API, my backend API uses basic authentication. I am running my app on `localhost:3000` and the server is also running on a different port.

## Below is my code

```js
const officeId = 1
        const locale = "en"
        const dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
        const active = false
        const pwd = "somevalue"
        const user = "somevalue"
        let apiHeader =  {
            'Authorization': "Basic " + Buffer.from(user + ':' + pwd).toString('base64'),
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "X-Fineract-Platform-TenantId": "somevalue",
        }
        const myUrl = "https://somevalue.com/api/v1/clients"

        let clientDetails = {
            firstname, lastname, emailAddress, mobileNo, idNumber, password,
            locale, dateFormat, active, officeId
        }
        //console.warn(clientDetails)
        err.preventDefault()
        // const result = ""
        try {

            let response = await fetch(myUrl, {
                mode: 'no-cors',
                method: 'POST',
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                headers: apiHeader,
                body: JSON.stringify(clientDetails),
            
            });
            let data = await response.json()
            
            return console.warn(data)
        } catch (err) {
            return console.warn(err)
        }

    }
```

I tried using mode "cors" but I get cors error.

Answer (score 0):

May be you havenot intsalled cors in your backend and haven't added to the backend. If you have used json to send it to the server then you have to add cors.

First of all, You have to install cors in your backend as:

```
npm install cors
```

then you have to add some of the lines in the main file of backend like: index.js or server.js as:

```
 var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

then set you mode to cors in the code you provided as:

```
   let response = await fetch(myUrl, {
            mode: 'cors',
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            headers: apiHeader,
            body: JSON.stringify(clientDetails),
        
        });
```